# Get "Target URL ... is not allowed" error message when actioning Outlook actionable message for external email user

Tags: office365api, office365-apps, office365connectors

We're developing a connector that creates actionable outlook messages for external users. I.E. This is a service. Can anyone please help with the below example? We're getting an error for the external users when they try to action the message by clicking on one of the action buttons.

Example:

User A is on the tenant that registered the connector - Tenant A, 
User B is on another Office 365 tenant, Tenant B.

We've created an Office 365 connector targeting the user's "Inbox"

[image: Inbox connector]

The connector has **not** been published to the store but is still in dev.

So to be clear we're not implementing our solution using "Actionable Email".

We can create the actionable message for both User A and B, no problems so both users get the email. But only User A ( on the tenant that registered the connector ) can click an Action button from Outlook. User B gets the error message:

"Target URL 'https://nameomitted.com/method' is not allowed"

We are not receiving anything at our web server end from the call. The console error from the browser when clicking the action button is:

[image: console error]

So the error is generated from Microsoft internally.

Can we only send to users in the same tenant as the one that registered the connector until we've published to the store? That seems restrictive for development.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your connector's registration pending or approved?

Pending connector's functionality is limited. Most cross tenant operations are blocked.

Comment: Thanks @Tony. Our connector is Pending approval as we are still in a test phase. As it happens Microsoft got back to me and confirmed what you state. Seems very limited to me that we have to basically put our connector in the store and thus go-live in order to beta test with external clients. Given that the external user has to authorize our connector themselves surely it should be up to them. Anyway, I've accepted your answer regardless as it's true and thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using a different URL which was not registered in the Provider. If both the end points (in the provider & in the Adaptive Card JSON) match, then only it will work.